# How to start "PsExec.exe" and using it how to start ".exe" with GUI in Web Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, psexec

I want to start "PsExec" and using it I want to launch ".exe" with GUI using web service.

I have created .asmx Web Service and hosted it in local IIS.

When trying to call web service from IIS, my GUI is not opening but runs in background. I read somewhere it is possible with the use of "PsExec".

For sample code:

```
Process myProc = new Process();
ProcessStartInfo stinfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
stinfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized;
stinfo.FileName = @"C:\ABC.exe";
stinfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
stinfo.UseShellExecute = false;

myProc = Process.Start(stinfo);
```

How to solve this?
Thanks!!

Comment: Have you tried using `psexec` to accomplish this from the command line (without using C#), then once you've figured that out you can wire it up in C#? I seem to recall some specific conditions you have to achieve in order to have `psexec` interact with the GUI on a remote machine, and I think [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/) may be a better site for getting help with that.

Comment: mason, I have not tried it, but run using c#, I am able to launch windows from visual studio server, not able to start window from IIS. Thanks